# Is the letter "d" sometimes pronounced like a glottal stop?

Tags: grammar, pronunciation

Is the letter "d" sometimes pronounced like a glottal stop? For example is the letter "d" in the word "wouldn't" pronounced like a glottal stop?

Comment: Only accent I can think of is Valley Girl, more with _didn’t_ than _wouldn’t_ though.

Comment: Sounds plausible in London ("Cockney") and Glasgow accents.

Answer (score 3):

Some English dialects have [T-glottalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-glottalization), in some cases voiceless p is glottalized and also some linguists talk about k-glottalization (but it's [uncommon](https://www.journal-labphon.org/articles/10.5334/labphon.70/)).

To my knowledge nobody claims that voiced "d" sound is ever glottalized in English. Strictly speaking you've asked about letter, not sound - in that case, well, you need to things: 1) this particular d is actually pronounced voiceless 2) it's glottalized.

Speaking of specifically "wouldn't" - I never read about this word being D-glottalized. In fact, /d/ in American dialects is indeed quite often indistinguishable from /t/ - both [medial t and d both sound](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/31814/can-medial-t-and-d-before-syllabic-n-be-distinguished-easily) as [[ɾ] (alveolar flap)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C9%BE), which shouldn't be confused with glottal stop. Also, as it said in the link provided, before a syllabic /n̩/ t become glottalized while d never does.

Also [this excellent question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/426473/is-d-glottalization-a-plausible-explanation-of-ambiguity-in-donald-trump-intervi) (and even more excellent answers provided) might give you some food for thoughts.

Comment: Actually, before /n/, many dialects of American English glottalize /t/ (as in *kitten* [ˈkɪʔn]) but not /d/ (as in *wooden* [ˈwʊdn]). So before /n/, they're usually distinguishable. See this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105011/what-is-the-proper-pronunciation-of-kitten).

Comment: @PeterShor my bad - I was rushing with an answer and just screwed up last two sentences - of course you are right, I've provided fixed answer.